# Do I need a visa to travel to South Africa with a Germany refugee travel document?

Tags: visas, refugees

Do I need a visa to travel to South Africa with a Germany refugee travel document? If yes, what is the requirement for the visa application at the South African embassy?

Answer (score 2):

According to a query on the [KLM Traveldoc](https://klm.traveldoc.aero/#results), a visa is *required for passengers holding travel documents issued to stateless persons or refugees or travel documents for aliens.*

The [South African Embassy to the Federal Republic of Germany](https://www.suedafrika.org/en/visa-immigration/visas-short-stay-not-exceeding-3-months.html) visa and immigration page notes that *[a]ll visa applicants must submit their applications in person during the consular business hours at the Embassy in Berlin or Consulate-General in Munich*.

The Consular Section in the Embassy in Berlin
Tiergartenstr. 18
10785 Berlin
Fax Consular Section: 030 22073 202
Email Consular Section: berlin.consular(at)dirco.gov.za

Residents of Bavaria and Baden-Wurttemberg must lodge applications and pay any applicable fees at the South African Consulate-General in Munich:

Südafrikanisches Generalkonsulat
Sendlinger-Tor-Platz 5
80336 Munich
Fax: 089 231 163 53
Email: munich.consular(at)dirco.gov.za

According to the [Republic of South Africa Department of Home Affairs](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/applying-for-sa-visa), the following documents are required to apply for a visa:

- A passport or travel document valid for no less than 30 days after the expiry of your intended visit
- Your passport must have at least TWO unused page for entry / departure endorsements
- A completed [Form BI-84](http://www.southafrica-newyork.net/consulate/forms/bi84.pdf) (application for a visa)
- Payment of the prescribed fee
- A yellow-fever vaccination certificate (if required)
- Statement and/or documentation confirming the purpose and duration of your visit
- Two colour passport photographs
- A return or onward ticket if you are travelling by air
- If you have children (minors) travelling with you or joining in South Africa, you will need to provide the following additional documents:
  → Proof of guardianship or custody or
  → Consent from the guardian in the case of an unaccompanied minor
- Proof of financial means to pay for your living expenses while in South Africa in the form of:
  → Bank statements
  → Salary advances
   
  → Undertakings by the host(s) in South Africa
  → Bursary
  → Medical cover or
  → Cash available (including credit cards and travellers’ cheques)