# Do I need a visa to travel to South Africa with an Australian convention travel document?

Tags: visas, south-africa, refugees

When travelling on an Australian travel document for refugees, do I need a visa to enter South Africa?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Travel.SE. Most of the answer in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103111/do-i-need-a-visa-to-travel-to-south-africa-with-a-germany-refugee-travel-documen) should apply to your case.